# Run a DotNetNuke application as http://localhost:8080/

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am totally new to Windows environment, Dot Net Development and Dot Net Nuke Development.   I'm primarily a LAMP developer.

Ok so I want to explore Dot Net Nuke and learn how to use it as a developer.  Yesterday, I successfully installed it to my localhost and ran it as a website with the url `http://localhost:<someportnumber>` .  I was able to edit pages in the DNN website through the web browser.  I was also able to find the css files and start changing the appearance of the site.  But today, after turning on my computer, I don't remember how to start up the website and what url+port number it's supposed to be on.

I remember there was some software that "started up" the website for me yesterday.  I'm guessing the software instructed IIS to serve the contents of `C:\Users\john\Documents\My Web Sites\dotnetnuke\` as a website with the url `http://localhost:<someportnumber>`.  But I can't remember the name of this software!

So then I went into the IIS Manager.  I stumbled around and tried to add a new site to the application pool.  I input the directory of the website, the host name, and the port number (this time i chose 8080).  But when i go to `http://localhost:8080/`, i get errors like

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
```

Can anyone tell me how to restart my dot net nuke website?  Assume I know nothing about the Windows operating system, that I'm use to doing things via terminal/bash in Linux.

**Additional notes**
I do have Visual Studios 2010 installed.  I also have SQL Server Management Studio 2008 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what software I used to start up the dotnetnuke project.  It's called Microsoft Web Matrix.  I opened that up, selected my dotnetnuke project, and it started the website.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting, that anyone who wishes to test the lastest Open Source projects can do so through the Microsoft Web Matrix program: http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/ Also worth noting is Microsoft's desire to gain ground in the server market :)

Answer (score 0):

To install it on a different port, I believe there is a setting in web.config.
"UsePortNumber"

I prefer installing it myself by using the Install package (not the source package).

DotNetNuke also provides some great videos on installing.  You have many options.

They have tons of great videos at: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library.aspx